# Vlan Trunk between SonicWall Soho Wireless N and Allied Telesis Switch

Tags: firewall, sonicwall, trunk

Hi I have the same problem I have SonicWall Soho Wireless N router, I made 3 Vlans ont the interface X0, I Created dynamic DHCP for each Vlan;

I have Allied Telesis Switch where I create the same 3 Vlans

But my problem is that I don't know how to do trunk on the SonicWall to attribuate IP addresses in differents Vlans on the switch. It seems not possible to trunking on this version of SonicWall?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your uplink port set to dot1q in your switch, and you create all VLAN you need to have access into your sonicwall in the corresponding interface

Don't forget to set the static ip into the interface, see [there](https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw13826)